# Where does the word (magic) cookie come from?

Tags: etymology, internet, terminology

Who named the file that websites can place on your computer for, for example advertising, and what is the connection with cookie as a food?

Comment: This is [General Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)

Comment: Hi, S., and welcome to EL&U. What have you found on looking these terms up, that you can share with us? Have you tried [Etymology Online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=cookie&searchmode=none)? What, if anything, would you like us to *help you understand*? Questions that show and share research (and difficulties) are appreciated here.

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot my manners. It's been a long day. Welcome to ELU; but I think everything you want to know is only a click away, and there's not much point in duplicating that information here.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Although I know it was pinned from magic cookie I am not sure why cookie was used instead of a "better" word like ticket or token.  I don't think Wikipedia answered the question, it just ports you to another question.  I guess this one could be reworded to where does magic cookie come from (why was it named that)?

Comment: Why was this closed? The "General Reference" link does not explain origin of the term "magic cookie". Since the sources being referenced for information don't claim to have the answer this should be left open. Perhaps an expert has an answer to this. The has an origin within "remembered" history, so I doubt it's strictly unknowable.

Comment: The answer that makes the most sense is that "cookie" comes from the Unix/hacker term "magic cookie", which refers to an "opaque" piece of data that is passed from program to program (e.g. web server to web browser) that is not meant to be understood by any program except the one that created it and is expected to be sent back unchanged. The Unix system call pair "ftell/fseek" is an older example.  The term "magic cookie" probably refers to fortune cookies, which hide the contents of their data. This fits in with the historical connection between hacker culture and Chinese food.

Comment: @BlueWhale Do you have a reference for the fortune cookie origin? Can you expand on the history connection between hacker culture and Chinese food? So far none of the sources on this page have explained the origin of "magic cookie" by definitively linking any of its characteristics to the word "cookie". The [wikipedia talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AMagic_cookie) has some theories but nothing definitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with answering this type of question is that there are at least a dozen different answers depending on the story you believe. Before cookies were given their official name, they were in use at hundreds of companies, each of which had their own name for the text files. Developers for UNIX, Sun, and Xerox all have a story regarding the origin, the most common of which you can find [here](http://cookiecontroller.com/internet-cookies/browser-cookies/).

I messaged a friend who was a lead developer at Netscape, and he offered the common Hansel and Gretel theory. To the extent you are looking for the connection to food, the answer is in the crumbs.

Comment: There’s something really bizarre about stringing *Unix, Sun,* and *Xerox* together like that. Unix is an operating system; the other two are companies, of which the first has had a great deal of influence in the development of Unix, while the second was an early forerunner in graphical user interfaces.